# Job monitoring for Node.js

Tags: node.js

Note: I asked the original question in "Software Engineering", but was advised to ask it here.

I want to monitor batch jobs which get triggered by an REST API. This batch jobs are long running native data processings. So naturally, I want to return immediately after a REST call e.g. uploaded some data, and the long running job was started.

I have two usage scenarios for job monitoring in mind: - An user of this API should be able to get the status of a job. So whether the task has finished, cancelled or is still running (ignoring progress for the moment) - An administrator should have an overview of all currently running jobs, and ideally which REST API calls triggered the jobs

I was leaning towards Spring XD for this. But since my application is not really about big data, I wonder if there is a more lightweight solution for NodeJS.

Comment: Do you want open source? Gratis? What budget? What operating system?

Comment: Do you need a job queue, where jobs are stored while waiting for an available worker? Do you want persistence? I mean, if your server crashes and reboots, should the job queue remain? Should the interrupted tasks be launched again? Do you have a preference for a database engine if needed?